# How to create a customized calendar to display just a particular Month on Button-click, with no Saturday and Sunday?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, button, calendar

I have a TextBox and a Button. **When I enter the Month and Year (Example: April, 2013) in the TextBox, and click on the button, a customized calendar for that particular Month should be displayed.**

**Note: There will be no Saturdays or Sundays in the calendar. Days will only be from Monday to Friday.**

It should be a **web-based ASP.NET application using C#.**

How can I do this customized calendar? **Provide a sample code that implements the above functionality.**

Comment: do you want to add any events on that calendar.? it s poosible to make ot my using gridview. if you want more help i can help you in this concept...

Comment: When I enter a Month , say for example, August 2013, in a TextBox, and click on a button, the calendar for that particular month should be displayed with no Saturdays and Sundays. It does not matter how you do it. Please give me that code for implementing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string month = txtMonth.Text;// should be in the format of Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc...
    int yearofMonth = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text);
    DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("01-" + month + "-" + yearofMonth);
    DataRow dr;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Monday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Tuesday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Wednesday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Thursday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Friday");
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month); i += 1)
    {
        txtMonth.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime.AddDays(0)).ToString("dddd");
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime.AddDays(i)).ToString("dddd") == "Monday")
        {
            dr["Monday"] = i + 1;
        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Tuesday")
        {
            dr["Tuesday"] = i + 1;
        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Wednesday")
        {
            dr["Wednesday"] = i + 1;

        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Thursday")
        {
            dr["Thursday"] = i + 1;
        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Friday")
        {
            dr["Friday"] = i + 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            continue;
        }
        if (i == DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month) - 1)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();

        }

    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

  }
}
```

and

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonth" runat="server">Mon</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtYear" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks...